# should I check relative error or percentage relative error?

Tags: c, error-handling

I have optimized `exponential` exp function. I am checking my output with respect to standard math `exp` functions .

`Res_opt` and `Res_std` is the two outputs I have .

I checked first with absolute error :

```
Abs_error = abs(Res_opt - Res_std )
```

I put `MAX_DEV = 0.500000` (BY CONSIDERING MY ALGORITHM)

and checking :

```
  if(Abs_error > MAX_DEV){
     printf("Error message").
     return 0;
   }
```

In few cases this `Abs_error` is coming greater than `0.50000` value and my test case is failing (But I felt for that input the derived result is fine as it is a corner case).

So I decided to check the relative error.

But my query is, should I check relative error or percentage relative error with below logic -

```
ACC_BAND = 0.400000000000000;
double min_acc_range = 1 - ACC_BAND;
double max_acc_range = 1 + ACC_BAND;

Relative_error =   abs(Res_opt - Res_std)/Res_std ;

if ((Relative_error < min_acc_range) || (Relative_error > max_acc_range)) {
 printf("Error message");
}
```

OR

```
Percentage_Relative_error =   1 - (abs(Res_opt - Res_std)/Res_std)*100 ;

if ((Percentage_Relative_error < min_acc_range) || (Percentage_Relative_error > max_acc_range)) {
 printf("Error message");
}
```

Comment: They end up the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You didn't measure it wrong ... this is all about accuracy.**
Here you use **Absolute Error**. But you can use **Percentage Relative Error** or **Relative Error**.

The **Percentage Relative Error** is the **Relative Error** measure as a percentage. Their's end accuracy will same in average case.

But good practices depends on your value limit.

In case of small value, percentage relative error is good because **1.0** and **2.0** is not near about where your upper limit value is **10.0**.

In case of bigger value, relative error is must better where **10000007** and **10000008** is near about.

So depends on your value limit you can decide.

Comment: Just one query ,should I take absolute value for the percentage relative error .  As some of my  percentage relative errors are coming negative .

Comment: Here your concern is how near that's two value. So yes you can use absolute value.